# Django/plotly.js: Pass Pandas Dataframe columns to template chart

Tags: javascript, python, django, pandas, plotly.js

I have a pandas dataframe (not user input) stored in my database as a csv. I extract this csv in my view, and then want to pass two columns to my template and into a plotly.js chart: a date column and a value column. How should I correctly pass these as template variables in order for plotly javascript to interpret them correctly?

attempted solution:

views.py

```py
def chart_function(request):
       df = #dataframe is extracted from DB using some code
       dates = list(pd.to_datetime(df['dates']))
       values = [float(i) for i in list(df['values'])]
       return render(request, template.html, {'values': values, 'dates': dates})
```

template.html:

```html
<div id="myDiv"></div>
<input type = "hidden" id = "dates" name = "variable" value = "{{dates|safe}}">
<input type = "hidden" id = "values" name = "variable" value = "{{values|safe}}">


<script type = "text/javascript">
var dates = document.getElementById("dates").value.split(',');
var values = document.getElementById("values").value.split(',');

var trace1 = {
  x: dates,
  y: values,
  type: 'scatter',
};


var data = [trace1];
Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data, {}, {showSendToCloud: true});
</script>
```

The plot actually plots somewhat correctly, but it's clear that the dates are not being passed as date objects because the x axis has dates within strings and brackets. I need the df columns to be recognized as dates/values by plotly javascript.

I think my halfway solution is a little hacked together, and is not being interpreted correctly by the chart.

heres a sample of the dataframe:

```py
Date          Value          
2019-01-03    3.0
2019-01-04    4.0
2019-01-05    5.0
2019-01-06    6.0
2019-01-07    7.0
2019-01-08    8.0
2019-01-09    9.0
2019-01-10   10.0
2019-01-11   11.0
2019-01-12   12.0
2019-01-13   13.0
2019-01-14   14.0
2019-01-15   15.0
2019-01-16   16.0
```

Comment: Could you post a snippet from the actual javascript `data` object?

Comment: Are you using hidden inputs to transfer data?

Comment: the data object in javascript, ```[trace1]```, is simply a renaming of the trace1 variable. is that what you mean? there is no other JS in my template

Comment: yes. the hidden inputs are taking the data as a variable, and then JS is calling the hidden inputs using get by ID

Comment: I meant if you could console.log() that variable it would make the date formatting obvious

Comment: added a sample of the data

Comment: You added a sample of the dataframe, though, it would be helpful to see a sample of the `trace1` object in javascript... if you add `console.log(trace1)` at the end of the script, you'll see the output in your chrome console when you look at the page; that's the actual data that Plotly is receiving.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your process here has a few steps:

1. Get the data out of your data storage (usually a database, but a CSV in this case)
2. Put that data in the template
3. Parse the data in JS
4. Plotly

Step 1 is great, but step 2 you have a bit of an odd methodology. Generally this is called serialization; I'd highly advise against using hidden inputs the way you are. Your goal is to translate your pandas dataframe into a JS variable, it's simpler than you think.

You can eliminate your hidden inputs by changing your javascript to just this:

```
var trace1 = {
  x: {{dates|safe}},
  y: {{values|safe}},
  type: 'scatter',
};


var data = [trace1];
Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data, {}, {showSendToCloud: true});
```

Because you can think of the Django template as just copy/paste: It's going to paste your data wherever you put that tag whether that's in the HTML part or the JS part.

For future reference, Pandas has a serialization method called `df.to_json()` which is built for this translation, and that has built-in options for controlling date formatting and stuff. That's the best tool to use but it's not technically necessary here. Docs: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_json.html

For the third step, plotly is expecting JS Date objects, and you're giving it strings--you need to parse them first using Date.parse()

One way you could do that would be to map the Date.parse() function over the array of date strings like so:

```
unparsedDates = {{dates|safe}}

parsedDates = unparsedDates.map(dateString => new Date(dateString) )

var trace1 = {
  x: parsedDates,
  y: {{values|safe}},
  type: 'scatter',
};


var data = [trace1];
Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data, {}, {showSendToCloud: true})
```

Comment: wow that really simplified my approach. what do you mean by Date.parse()? it seems to be correctly reading the dates as so

Comment: Yeah I'm not 100% sure that's necessary. Plotly.js documentation says it parses JS Date objects, but there are a few examples floating around saying that as long as the timestamps are in UTC format then Plotly.js can handle the strings. Yours are already in UTC format because that is the Pandas default.

Comment: @DeathbyGreen I added an example I think might work (though I haven't tested it and I'm better in Python than JS) so maybe try that and see if it fixes your axis problem?

Comment: ill check that out. plotly seems to be doing fine with the axis; its now auto interpreted into dates and looks really nice; all the quotes and brackets are gone

Comment: It's possible the process of putting it into and removing it from the input fields was changing the delimiters!

Comment: I tested this method, in chrome console, I get this error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: Timestamp is not defined`. in source tab of inspect of chrome the data is like : `unparsedDates = [Timestamp('2018-05-29 08:09:00'),`. any ideas?

Comment: @Ryan please check [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65335321/how-to-send-datetime-dataframe-to-django-template-and-plot-it-in-js-using-plotly)