# how to send datetime dataframe to django template and plot it in js using plotly

Tags: javascript, django, dataframe, datetime-format, python-datetime

I have a data-frame and I want to send it in my Django template.

dummy code in `views.py`:

```
def graphs(request):

    df_new = pd.read_excel("/home/cms/cms/static/Sensorik.xlsx")

    times = df_new.loc[:, df_new.columns[0]].to_json(orient='records') 
    # columns[0] contains datetime values
    
    data_color = df_georgian.loc[:, df_georgian.columns[2]]
    color = data_color.to_json(orient='records')

    context = {
        'times': times,
        'data_color': color,
        ...
        }
    return render(request, 'graphs/graphs.html', context)
```

In my template, I get these data like the following:

```
<script>
    var times = {{ times|safe }};
    console.log('index: ', typeof(index));
    var color = {{ data_color|safe }};
</script>
```

the `color` variable is totally ok but the `times` variable when get to JSON format turns  from `2018-05-29 08:09:00` format to something like it:

> element:  1528108200000

I want to be able to plot the `color` based on `times` to get a line graph with plotly. i.e. I want to show `times` as x-ticks of my plot.

any suggeston on

**1- how to send datetime dataframe to django template?**

or

**2- how to convert `element:  1528108200000` into a datetime in js to plot it as x-ticks?**

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you see something that should be a date or time expressed in a large number like the `1528108200000` format, that means it is or is similar to a UNIX timestamp—the number of seconds past January 1, 1970. In this case, the length of the timestamp indicates that it's milliseconds, not seconds, so it's not exactly a UNIX timestamp but is very close.

Milliseconds since January 1, 1970 is the way that [JS internally stores `Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) objects, which is interesting because it means some sort of conversion is probably happening on the JS side, not the python side (where you'd usually get ISO format or UNIX Timestamps).

In any case, it's pretty easy to solve on the JS side because you can simply parse the number:

```
dateObject = new Date(1528108200000);
```

If you do that parsing and pass the data to Plotly as `Date` objects, Plotly should be able to recognize your dates.

A simple way to do that would be:

```
const times = [1528108200000, 1528108200000, 1528108200000]
const parsed = times.map(time => new Date(time))
```

assuming your `times` variable is just an array of these integers.